# In Skip-Gram model, what is the intuition of taking average of input word matrix and output word matrix?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word2vec

In the skip-gram model, we have input word matrix $W$, and output word matrix $W'$.
The final word embedding we got, is the average of $W$ and $W'$.
what is the intuition of taking average of $W$ and $W'$? Why should we do that?

[image]